# How do I use the template of a theme that isn't my parent theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've made a child theme based on Theme A (Parent Theme). However, the search template of that theme isn't all that great. But the search template (only that template)of Theme B is awesome.

What do I have to do (in terms of coding), so my search results are based on Theme B Search Template?

Comment: So Theme B is the child?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no easy way you can do it.
The only option you have is to look in theme B code and find everything related to search. Then try to understand it and copy it or replicate it in theme A.
Unfortunately WordPress has no real standard on how a theme should be *templeted*, so different themes can have as many files as they would like and/or need to; the same goes for naming conventions for template parts and features.